# Variety (zero set) mapping onto another

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The map $$\phi: \mathbb{A}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto ((x+1)yz^2,yz,yz^2)$$ maps the variety $V(x^2+y^2-1)$ onto the variety $V(x^2+y^6-2xyz)$, V denoting the zero-set of the polynomial.

How does one see that?

(as stated in *Today’s Menu: Geometry and Resolution of Singular Algebraic Surfaces* (2009) by E. Faber , H. Hauser, pp. 375, 376)

Comment: You would go through the algebra and show that any point with coordinates satisfying the first relation gets sent under the map to a point with coordinates satisfying the second relation. This doesn't actually happen here, though, as $(\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}},1)\mapsto (\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ and inputting this last point in to $x^2+y^6-2xyz$ gives $3/8$, not $0$ as you would want. Perhaps there's a typo?

Comment: Indeed, I find that the image is contained in $\mathbb{V}(x^2 + y^4 - 2xz)$.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your thoughts, KReiser and André! I see every step of your reasoning, KReiser, although the typo might only lie in the original. Also, I see the same as you, André, like in a blow up. There might be one blow up map missing to acually get to $V(x^2+y^6-2xyz)$, as in $$V(x^2+y^6-2xyz) \mapsto V(x^2+y^4-2xz) \mapsto V(x^2+y^2-z^2) \mapsto V(x^2+y^2-1).$$